# Is this a good idea -- using symlinks to rationalize behavior of Python distribution tools

Tags: python, distribution

Short version --

Is it safe to symlink together multiple Python path / install locations so all reference the same files -- to paper over a messy history of installations using different distribution tools & options?

Longer version --

One area of Python that's mystified me longer than others :) is the diverse behavior of the various distribution tools (although [this reference](http://guide.python-distribute.org/installation.html) is pretty froody).

One of the issues is default install locations.  My belief (maybe incorrect) is that it's hard to avoid using more than one distribution tool, and each has a different opinion about where packages should be installed.  It's easy to end up with packages in multiple locations, and if you're using more than one Python brand / system, you then need to explicitly manage Python path if you want to use the same libraries from more than one environment / brand / system.

I now understand how to avoid this problem using the distro tools options that explicitly name the install directory to use, and / or via virtualenv.  However I also need to solve the problem I currently have without rejiggering my system & re-installing a bunch of things.

My solution to this was to move the contents of all but one folder to the one remaining folder, and recreate the others as symbolic links to the one remaining folder.  So far it seems to work well.  Can you think of any downsides to this approach?  It seemed a little too easy :)

Comment: Which `test/` directory gets priority?

Comment: Not sure but I suppose whichever name -- directory containing real files, symlinked directory A or symlinked directory B -- the particular Python has first in its path.  What would that affect?

Comment: are all the packages for the same version of Python? I (think?) I've seen some packages get compiled only for one version, but not super sure about it. Also, what makes you think that pip and easy_install use different install locations?